# Spatial cluster analysis

Tags: clustering, spatial

Let's say I have a structure like this :

[image]

This is a spatial region with measurement of plant population in each site. Black and red represent two regions with different intensities.The question is that I want to ask about the degree of spatial dependency. I've tried Moran's I statistic, but I think Moran's I can only tell us if the spread is spatially independent or not. Is there a way to test about spatial dependency but also to tell if we have different clusters on it ? Like in this example, I know that I have 2 different clusters (black and red).

Comment: An extension of Moran's I is to calculate the *local* Moran's I value for every unit on the map. Then plot the outliers in LISA maps, which would typically show your clusters that you illustrate. See Exercise 19 (page 138) of the [GeoDa workbook](http://geodacenter.asu.edu/system/files/geodaworkbook.pdf) for an example.

Comment: @AndyW your link rotted. I *think* the new place is [here](http://geodacenter.github.io/workbook/6a_local_auto/lab6a.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is also a package in `R` called `spdep` in which you can perform the global (`lm.morantest()`) and local (`spautolm()`) spatial autocorrelation. Both measurements will answer with the the actual index plus the p-value. Remember that the hypothesis null of Moran's I is Complete Spatial Randomness.